# Missing operand after 'L' operator

Tags: c#

I am getting below error in my code:

> Missing operand after 'L' operator.

I debugged the code and found that it is occurring in below line:

```
DataRow[] documents = this.DataSet.Results_Documents.Select(String.Format("DocumentControlNumber = '{0}'", dcn), null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Here it is occurring when dcn contains `'` in its full string.

What is the exact reason for this?

**For example: dcn :- Nat'l Bk of Sheldon**

Comment: Sample values for `dcn`??

Comment: Why would a document _number_ contain an apostrophe?  Do you need to replace the single quote with two singe quotes to escape it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here it is occurring when dcn contains `'` in its full string.

Yup; a common problem with using concatenation; let's use the example `dcn` as `Nat'l Bk of Sheldon` from you question; the query is now:

```
DocumentControlNumber = 'Nat'l Bk of Sheldon'
```

which is malformed. Since this doesn't allow proper parameterization, you will need to "escape" the value; If I had to guess, to one of:

```
DocumentControlNumber = 'Nat''l Bk of Sheldon'
```

or

```
DocumentControlNumber = 'Nat\'l Bk of Sheldon'
```

(noting that the `\` n C# **also** needs escaping, or use of verbatim string literals)

Either should be achievable via a `string.Replace`; for example `dcn.Replace("'","''")` (in the parameter to `string.Format`).

Answer (score 2):

The `Select` requires the string to be in a specific format, when you have a `'` the string is no longer valid. You need to escape quotes by repacing every `'` with `''`

```
DataRow[] documents = this.DataSet.Results_Documents.Select(
                            String.Format("DocumentControlNumber = '{0}'"
                                         , dcn.ToString().Replace("'", "''")
                            ), null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

if `dcn` is a `string` you don't need the `.ToString()`